# Разом чи окремо "пів" у "малюкам віком від пів/року"

Tags: іменники, правопис, разом-дефіс-окремо

За новим правописом-2019, числівник "пів" з іменниками пишеться окремо. Та "півроку" (як слово писалося до змін) має два значення: 1. половина року як проміжок часу; 2. вік, що дорівнює половині року. 
Проблема виникла з тим, як слід, відповідно до норм нової редакції правопису, писати "пів/року" у конструкціях "харчування для малюків віком від пів/року", "прикорм можна починати з пів/року" тощо, де йдеться саме про вік немовляти. 
До якої з категорій, визначених у [примітці](https://prnt.sc/rktd13) в правописі-2019, на вашу думку, слід зараховувати "пів/року" в значенні "вік"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В обох наведених значеннях *пів року* за новим правописом пишеться окремо.

Розглянемо на прикладі "*пів[ ]о́строва*". Щоб з'ясувати, як слід писати -- *піво́строва* чи *пів о́строва* -- у певному контексті, треба поставити це слово/словосполучення в називний відмінок (не втрачаючи зв'язку з контекстом):

- Якщо буде "*пів[ ]о́стрів*", то це одне слово, що пишеться разом -- *піво́стрів*, *піво́строва*, *піво́стровом*, *на піво́строві*. Наприклад, "*Квазінезія розташована за 100 км на схід від пів[ ]о́строва*" -- *"пів[ ]о́стрів розташований за 100 км на захід від Квазінезії"* -- отже *піво́стрів*, *піво́строва*. Часто в такому випадку оце *пів-* має значення "наполовину" (наприклад, *піво́стрів* -- "наполовину о́стрів"), хоча може бути по-різному.
- Якщо буде "*пів[ ]о́строва*", то це два слова, що пишуться окремо -- *пів о́строва*. Наприклад, "*через тиждень після того, як перший інфікований пацієнт потрапив на острів, епідемія захопила вже пів[ ]о́строва*" -- "*через тиждень після того, як перший інфікований пацієнт потрапив на острів, вже пів[ ]о́строва було захоплено епідемією*" -- отже *пів о́строва*. *Пів* у такому випадку завжди має значення "половина (від)" (*пів о́строва* -- "половина (від) о́строва").

У Вашому випадку якби називним відмінком було "*піврік*" ("*піврік має виповнитися малюку перш ніж...*"), то писалося б разом, а якщо називний відмінок *пів року* (*"пів року має виповнитися малюку перш ніж..."*), то за новим правописом пишеться окремо. Але в літературній українській мові взагалі немає слова "*піврік*" (лише *півріччя* або *пів року*). Тому *пів року* завжди окремо.

P.S.: Трішки іншими словами: якщо за контекстом це повноцінне слово, яке нормально відмінюється -- *північ*, *півночі*, *північчю* -- то пишемо разом. Якщо це явно половина чогось -- "*пів ночі я не міг заснути*" -- й інших форм окрім як "пів + родовий відмінок" воно не має (навіть якщо зробити його підметом: "ці пів ночі дуже мене втомили") -- то пишемо окремо.